# Groovy Dynamic arguments

Tags: groovy

I wonder how is this possible in groovy to start an array from the n element.

Look at the snippet :

```
static void main(args){

    if (args.length < 2){
        println "Not enough parameters"
        return;
    }

    def tools = new BoTools(args[0])
    def action = args[1]

    tools."$action"(*args)

    System.exit(1)

}
```

As you see am doing here a dynamic method invocation. The first 2 arguments are taken as some config and method name , the others I would like to use as method paramerts.
So how can I do something like this :

```
tools."$action"(*(args+2))
```

Edited : If not possilbe in native groovy Java syntax will do it :

```
def newArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args,2,args.length);
tools."$action"(*newArgs)
```

Comment: That `System.exit(1)` is pointless. Java isn't C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove items from the beginning of the `args` you can use the [`drop()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#drop%28int%29) method. The original args list is not changed:

```
tools."$action"(*args.drop(2))
```

Other option, like you are trying is to access from N element:

```
tools."$action"(*args[2..-1])
```

Comment: +1 for range notation. It is tidy and we already know we have >= 2 values.